# Override SVG inline styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

```
 <svg id="mb-one_top" style="position: absolute; top: -215px;"  
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="600" height="862" viewBox="0 0 600 862">
```

I'm trying to make my *SVG* smaller on mobile devices, so using *jQuery* i've written :

```
var width = $(window).width();
if (width == 320) {
    $('#mb-one_top').attr('width', '350');
}
```

But it isn't overriding and making my SVG width from 600 to 350, any idea?

Comment: You probably want `width < 600` rather than `width == 320`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve this easily using CSS code like this

```
<style>
    /* styles for mobile browsers smaller than 480px; (iPhone) */
    @media (max-width:480px){
        #mb-one_top {
             width : 350px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Yes but because I have the width set on the SVG inline. Then inline styles will always override any styles I add via stylesheet

Comment: Although i think this should do the trick but you could use important to override any styles `width: 350px !important`.